# Why is the output of the following recursive code 5 3 1 1 3 5? Should'nt it be 5 3 1 -1 1 3 5. ? The function is called by -1 also.? Please explain?

Tags: java, recursion

Here is the reference Program Code :-
The Program must also give -1 as the output. However I cant find the reason. Please Explain, and tell me the Stack which would be made.

```
class test
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {

  test ob=new test();
  ob.numbers(5);
 }


public void numbers(int n)
{

 if(n>0)
{
  System.out.print(n+" ");
  numbers(n-2);
  System.out.print(n+" ");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Even without the new object, It would give the same Output.The theme is, why the output is so?

Comment: You say *The Program must also give -1 as the output.* but then in my comments you say it mustn't - please explain yourself clearly.

Comment: Oh! Cmon, i said the Ouput is 5 3 1 1 3 5 . And (according to me) it should be 5 3 1 -1 1 3 5. My question is Why its not the way I think it should be? Look at jeffry's answer. He stated that clearly and explained. My question was clear. maybe you misunderstood. Thank you for your efforts . I got the solution anyways. And please don't down vote the question, ony if u dont understand. That's hurting for begginers like me. Peace. :-)

Comment: Without clean indentation, no clean mind. What is that Scanner doing there? Can you delete it, while fixing the indentation?

Comment: This was actually a User Input code, but i made it more specific by calling the function by Number 5. Scanner does no harm here, Nor make a slight contradiction to my output or my question. Maybe it's the numbers(int n) function we are more concerned about. Not the driving function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Call Stack goes this way:

numbers(n) // n = 5
{
  n>0 ? YES
  Print n -- Print 5
  call numbers(n-2) //n-2 = 3

    numbers(n) // n=3
    {
      n>0 ? YES
      Print n -- Print 3
      call numbers(n-2) //n-2 = 1

        numbers(n) // n=1
        {
          n>0 ? YES
          Print n -- Print 1
          call numbers(n-2) //n-2 = -1

            numbers(n) // n=-1
            {
              n>0 ? NO As Per the code, does nothing
            }
          Print n -- Print 1
        }
     Print n -- Print 3
   }
  Print n -- Print 5
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you jeffry. This was my solution.

Comment: Thats great! Responding to the comment you had posted in the other answer. It doesn't print -1 because the print statements are within the if block where the condition allows only if n is greater than 0.